# how to convert this type of mathematics in json?

Tags: json, string, math

I am trying to convert this type mathematics in JSON `∑i(Fi−miai)δri=0` and it shows some error.
I tried this `{"math" : ∑i(Fi−miai)δri=0}` but it doesn't work. So, how can I do this in JSON. Thank you.

Comment: For future: never say “shows some error.” Include the error message since it is meaningful. Errors aren’t shown just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `{"math" : "∑i(Fi−miai)δri=0"}` instead. You need to insert it as a string.